# Trust Webcam on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, software-installation, webcam

My Trust WB-1400T webcam does not work on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried using `cheese` &`Skype` but nothing seems working. Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 5):

> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2460 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Q-TEC WEBCAM 100

You will most likely need the *video4linux* support libraries.

Check if you have them already.

```
 locate v4l1compat.so
```

In my case, the output is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`, yours might be different if you're on 32bit.

If it't not there, just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
```

and try to locate it again.

Try to launch cheese with **preloading** the library

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/your-path-to-lib/v4l1compat.so cheese
```

TLDP has some background information on shared libraries and their [preloading](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: it does not work.when I open cheese the light appears phosphorescent and the rest just blank

Answer (score 1):

first you have to check is the camera is attached
start the terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
then execute `lsusb`, do you see something like ?

`Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093rd: 260th Pixart Imaging, Inc.`

Comment: No. I see this :

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2460 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Q-TEC WEBCAM 100 Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute this command:

```
gstreamer-properties
```

click **Video** try `v4l1` and `v4l2`

click the bottom <kbd>test</kbd> button for each one.

910 and up cheese webcam boothe is/should be installed if not already installed. Check for sound & video. Try the cam in cheese

Reply what happens. Hope it works. :)

<sub>**Source**:[Webcam Problem: Trust Wb 1400T](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499884)</sub>

Comment: it does not work.when I open cheese the light appears phosphorescent and the rest just blank

Comment: Now you have two choices. 1st try the answer given by 3rd person 2nd, **try [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1230164&page=2)**

Comment: nothing seems working. that's  what appears :ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/your-path-to-lib/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

(cheese:4291): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel