# Microdia webcam not seen on Dell Laptop

Tags: 18.04, webcam

Using Xubuntu 18.04 on a Dell laptop that does not have a web camera.
I bought an external webcam that advertised as being compatible with ubuntu.  Plugged in, `lsusb` sees it, but it will not show an image on cheese.

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia
```

I think the video driver for the camera is not present.

How do I get/make the appropriate service to use the web camera?
Or is these some other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I too have a Microdia webcam, and mine works, albeit the colours seem very washed out compared to how the same camera appears on Windows.
Mine shows up as:
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:624e Microdia PC Camera (SN9C201 + SOI968)
You will most likely need the video4linux support libraries.
Check if you have them already. In terminal, do:

```
locate v4l1compat.so
```

If yours are in (most likely, and assuming you have a 64bit linux)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
Assuming you want to see the webcam output in cheese, create a file as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so cheese
```

save it as a script, mine is called ´cheesefix.sh´ (yes, cheesy!)
then look at the file permissions, make it executable.
finally do (in terminal)

```
./cheesefix.sh
```

or whatever you called it.

this is actually heavily based on

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/418356/trust-webcam-on-ubuntu-12-04
```

Comment: Two years later, I have a new laptop with a microdia camera 0c45:6728 and also the colors are very washed out. I'm wondering if you ever managed to fix that issue?